# Modal Bottom sheet with FAB

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I have implemented persistent bottom sheet with FAB anchored to the top of it.

[image: bottom sheet]

When I try to do the same with modal bottom sheet (extends BottomSheetDialogFragment) it says

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find CoordinatorLayout descendant view to anchor view android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Is it possible to do the same layout with modal bottom sheet or maybe make a shadow and unclickable area above persistent one?

Comment: Hi, did you managed to do this ?

Comment: @oleg.semen unfortunately, no

Comment: Hi, any news about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same "FAB on top" thing in ModalBottomSheet, but there's no direct method/way to do that. 
For such cases, we therefore use [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout). Inside the definition, it says that -

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

So we can create a layout for the ModalBottomSheet (extends BottomSheetDialogFragment), which would look something like this in your case -

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_frame_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ModalBottomSheetFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Whatever layout you want to give here. This is going to be the body
        of the ModalBottomSheet. Also you might not wanna use the current Linear 
        Layout too.-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_sheet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_music"
        android:elevation="20dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Notice that -

1. FAB is made after LinearLayout (body for the BottomSheet), as it would be stacked over the LinearLayout.
2. We gave a marginTop=25dp for LinearLayout but we gave marginTop=0dp for the FAB. This is how you create the half-out, half-in effect. And also gave elevation on FAB for better float look.

Finally we can inflate it's view inside the *onCreateDialog* overridden method and perform all necessary actions thereafter.

Hope I was able to answer your question. Do comment for any further doubts/updates.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Krishn Agarwal answer we need to make sure the bottom sheet dialog has a transparent theme then only the same look and feel will be achieved. We can even have a Constraint Layout instead of a Linear Layout. We can use BottomSheetDialog/BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/parent_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_success_dialog"
            style="@style/AppModalStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_60"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_25"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_25"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_25">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title_text"
                style="@style/style_bottomsheet_header_22sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="@string/mf_mandate_creationsuccessful" />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                style="@style/open_sans_semi_bold_15sp_gray"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_7"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_25"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/go_to_dashboard_btn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title_text"
                tools:text="Description" />
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/go_to_dashboard_btn"
                style="@style/mf_style_blue_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:text="@string/mf_go_to_dashboard"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_description"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
      <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_tick_icon"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/very_light_green"
            app:elevation="@dimen/margin_20"
            app:fabCustomSize="128dp"
            app:maxImageSize="128dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_success_tick"
            app:tint="@null" />
    </FrameLayout>
```